# About entity transient attribute in core data

Tags: core-data

I have an entity with an transient attribute, and it's optional flag is set to NO.
If I fetch an instance of this entity from persistent store, change something and save back, need I set this transient attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Transient values are not saved at all so optional or required has no effect on them.</strike>

---

### Update:

Okay, I got that completely wrong. I am in the habit of setting default values and/or my transients always have calculated values so I'd forgotten that required transients do have to have a value. I tested it make sure.

If you have a transient attributes without values and its required the logic of the app should enforce that. Since you don't seem to use the transient every time, I suggest setting a default value or calculating the value in a custom getter method.

Comment: but in my test, save will fail if leave required transient attribute nil.

Comment: thank you. I also found that setting default value is a good way